# Gtk.Notebook page labels with wrong style using python gtk3

Tags: python, gtk3

I am currently writing an application in Python/Gtk3 that uses a `Gtk.Notebook` in its main window. The page tabs of the notebook all use a `Gtk.Label` to display the page name.

I came across the following weird behavior, and was wondering whether it is due to my mistake, or a bug that I should file to the Gtk3 developers.

First, let me show the 'suspicious' code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Example without Gtk.Box")
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)

        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.notebook)

        self.page1 = Gtk.Label('Label 1')
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label('Page 1'))

        self.page2 = Gtk.Label('Label 2')
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page2, Gtk.Label('Page 2'))

        self.page3 = Gtk.Label('Label 3')
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page3, Gtk.Label('Page 3'))

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Here, the notebook pages (e.g., `self.page1`) are always `Gtk.Label` objects that are directly appended to the notebook.

The result looks like this:

[image: Gtk.Notebook with Gtk.Label pages]

The style of the active label "Page 1" is black/bold (which is correct), the style of label "Page 3" is grey/bold (again, correct) but the style of the label "Page 2" is normal/black (which is wrong!). When hovering the mouse over the label "Page 2", the label will become bold, and as it needs more space, the label "Page 3" jumps to the right. This cannot be right.

In addition, after randomly switching between page tab labels several (10...20) times, a click on the window title will lead to style changes in the page tab labels, and hence, again, jumping labels.

Now the slightly modified code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Example with Gtk.Box")
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)

        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.notebook)

        self.page1 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page1.add(Gtk.Label('Label 1'))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label('Page 1'))

        self.page2 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page2.add(Gtk.Label('Label 2'))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page2, Gtk.Label('Page 2'))

        self.page3 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page3.add(Gtk.Label('Label 3'))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page3, Gtk.Label('Page 3'))

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The only difference here is that the notebook pages are `Gtk.Box` objects, to which the `Gtk.Label` objects are added.

The result looks as intended ("Page 2" and "Page 3" with same and correct style):

[image: Gtk.Notebook with Gtk.Box pages]

The content of the page is now left-aligned, but this is likely due to the `Gtk.Box` behavior and can be changed.

However, this code does not exhibit any other weird behavior. I can switch randomly between pages of the notebook as much as I want without trouble.

So the first question is:
Is there a mistake that I made in the first version (my initial version)? As far as I know, appended pages of `Gtk.Notebook` objects should be `Gtk.Widget` objects. Both `Gtk.Label` and `Gtk.Box` inherit from `Gtk.Widget`, so it should make no difference (?).

And secondly:
Is there anybody who can reproduce the weird behavior of the first attached code sample?

Comment: I can reproduce both images, so I think this is indeed a Gtk bug that should be reported.

Comment: @B8vrede Thanks for testing. Meanwhile, I could also reproduce the bug using C++/gtkmm. So I submitted a bug report to gtk+.

Comment: What makes you think the styles should be as you mention in "black/bold (which is correct), the style of label "Page 3" is grey/bold (again, correct) but the style of the label "Page 2" is normal/black (which is wrong!). When hovering the mouse over the label "Page 2", the label will become bold, and as it needs more space, the label "Page 3" jumps to the right"?
(I see no CSS style code applied to the names of your labels in any of your code blocks)

Comment: @skittlebiz I posted this question several years ago, and I haven't used Gtk3 since a long time, so I won't be able to comment on details ... but: the intended look of the widget can be seen here: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/notebook.png  Of course, the overall look depends on the activated theme but I used the same default theme as in the linked GTK3 documentation. The theme is also the reason why bold/black or bold/grey text is expected for the page tab labels.  Normal labels stay as they are but in certain places (e.g. notebook tab labels), the GTK3 theme adds CSS on top.